# What is the algorithm behind the axis option in numpy?

Tags: arrays, numpy

I cannot understand how axis in numpy works for **any general n-D array**.

For example, `np.mean(array, axis=1)` will give an expected array regardless of the shape of the `array`.

If I want to make a code without using numpy, I can make averaging function for k-D array, e.g., `mean_1d`, `mean_2d`, ... with axis option. However, I cannot imagine how to make a single function which works for any input array with any k value. So far, I couldn't find an explanation how numpy axis works. Can anybody help me understanding what's going on behind the scene?

Added: My original goal was to make a code to do a fast array combination with outlier rejection (i.e., sigma-clipped median combine of a list of n-D arrays and obtain an (n-1)-D array) using numba.

Comment: `np.mean` (and other functions like `np.sum`  and `np.max`) are compiled (builtin), so it's hard to explain "how axis works" in terms of Python code.  You just have to experiment with some simple arrays (I like one with a (2,3,4) shape) to see exactly what happens.  The easiest way to copy this behavior is to use these `numpy` functions.  I don't think it's possible to get the same flexibility when using `numba` (but I'm not a `numba` expert).

Comment: Understanding how arrays are stored, and especially how it uses `shape` and `strides` to iterate over the array is key to understanding `numpy` indexing, and most of these 'reduction' methods.

Comment: Is your question regarding how axis works or how it is implemented?

Answer (score 0):

If the size of your arrays allow you can see it recursively. I have just tested the code below and it seems to work fine for sum function along axis 3. It is simple but it should convey the idea :

```
import numpy as np

a = np.ones((3,4,5,6,7))

# first get the shape of the result
def shape_res(sh1, axis) :
    sh2 = [sh1[0]]

    if len(sh1)>0 :
        for i in range(len(sh1)) :
            if i > 0 and i != axis :
                sh2.append(sh1[i])
            elif i == axis :
                # shrink the summing axis
                sh2.append(1)
    return sh2


def sum_axis(a, axis=0) : 
    cur_sum = 0
    sh1 = np.shape(a)
    sh2 = shape_res(sh1, axis)

    res = np.zeros(sh2)
    print(sh1, sh2)

    def rec_fun (a, res, cur_axis) :
        for i in range(len(a)) :
            if axis > cur_axis :
                # dig in the array to reach the right axis
                next_axis = cur_axis + 1
                rec_fun(a[i], res[i], next_axis)
            elif axis == cur_axis :
                # sum along the given axis
                res[0] += a[i]

    rec_fun(a, res, cur_axis)
    return res

result = sum_axis(a, axis=3)
print(result)
```